# Los productos no se me separan por categoria

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, navbar, react-router-dom

Estoy creando una pagina, en el navbar tengo los categorías para separar los productos, la situación es que no los separa. Ejemplo en esta captura de mi Google Firebase [image: Ejemplo en esta captura de mi Google Firebase]

la "categoryId" es  "películas y series" (un compañero me comento que no debe haber espacios ahí, así que lo tengo como "películas-y-series"), en el router.js esta como

```
        <Router>
        <main className="routes">
            <NavBar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Container />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path=":categoryId/:categoryId">
                        <Container />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/item/:id">
                        <DContainer />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/cart">
                        <Cart/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
        </main>
    </Router>
```

En el navbar.js esta :

```
            <header className="navbar">   
            <div>
                <ul className="navbar-container">
                    <NavLink to='/'><img src={img} className="logo" alt="logo"/></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/categoryId/peliculas-y-series">
                        <li>Peliculas y Series</li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/categoryId/televisores">
                        <li>Televisores</li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/categoryId/ambiente">
                        <li>Ambiente</li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <CartWidget/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Y no los separa, que es lo que la pasa a mi pagina??

Comment: ¿No separa qué o cómo? No se entiende tu pregunta.

Comment: es una pagina simple, tengo todos los productos para que se vean al abrir la pagina, en el navbar, si queres, podes separarlos por categorias: "peliculas y series", tengo otra de "televisores" y otra de "ambiente", y los separa por esas categorias los productos. Pero el problema es que no lo hace, lo pagina se queda en blanco.